# Как вызвать finish() из статического метода (static method)?

Tags: android-studio

Как вызвать finish() из статического метода (static method)?

Или может быть чем-нибудь заменить finish()?

Нужно прекратить выполнение приложения (типа finish() сделать что-то из статического метода)

В классе (в котором находится этот статический метод) нет метода onCreate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Просто скопирую ответ на ваш предыдущий вопрос с заменой одного слова:

У статического метода не доступа к активиити. Для того что бы вызвать сообщение из него, передайте `Activity` в качестве входящего параметра. Например:

```
public static void test(Activity activity) {
    activity.finish()
}
```